# How to get into html source code by rest request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rest, fetch

I want to render some  value of another website by fetching the HTML source data by REST request, console the value inside the span tag to my console log and render it to my HTML.

I can't managed to this by my current code, he receives the data before  the DOM is ready and the specific san tag i need still not there.

**My current code -**

```
async function uiTagChecking() {

        let url ='http://production.com:8000/loginPage#';

        fetch(url)
            .then(await sleep(6000))
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(pageSource => console.log(pageSource));
}
```

**The current source code I've fetched *(this is before the DOM is ready and the needed span tag doesn't there yet)***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>loading...</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="icon"
        type="image/png"
        href="images/favicon.png?v=9">
  <!--<link href="assets/vendors/keylines/map/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

<link href="XXXX" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="XXXX/index-c08574aac712ae81e016.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

The span tag i want to print and render -

```
<span class="version-for-qa">2.1.1</span>
```

But it appears only after the redirect is ended and the DOM is ready.

**Technical info:**

Node JS

JavaScript

HTML + CSS

**My server file (express):**

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var fetch = require('fetch-cookie')(require('node-fetch'));
var btoa = require('btoa');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');


var corsOptionsDelegate = function (req, callback) {
    var corsOptions;
    if (whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
        corsOptions = { origin: true } // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
    }else{
        corsOptions = { origin: false } // disable CORS for this request
    }
    callback(null, data , corsOptions) // callback expects two parameters: error and options
};

app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/view');
app.set('view engine', 'html');


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
    res.render('logo');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
});

app.use(cors());

app.set(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
});


app.listen(8033, function () {
    console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 8033')
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the request via the client or server? Is this a cross domain request? If so, do you own the domain you're calling, and does it include CORS headers?

Comment: Yes it's a cross domain use case, I'll add my server.js as well